# Is this uniform is from India or Burma in the 1800's?

Tags: identification, british-empire, uniform

Is this an Indian Brigade? Possibly RSF in India or Burma?

[image]

Comment: The screenshot is barely perceptible; can you do anything to improve the image quality?  Do you have any context at all for the photo?

Comment: Please [edit] to ensure that the picture is of the best quality you can get it to (ideal: scan the original; at least extract it from the PDF), and try to show how you figure that this is "1800s" (mitres and _only_ halberds? -> looks older than 1800s) and why "Indian" (soldiers 'in' or 'from' India? Uniform reminds me of Madras Europeans, but details are sketchy). Provide more detail to where you got it from, what text accompanies the picture, notes/markings on the backside…) The more detail in resolution or context, provenience of it, the better.

Comment: Apart from bad picture quality, there is *way* to much personal information in this screenshot. Please reduce your picture to the amount needed for this question. This will be the automatic side effect of giving us a better copy of the photo, and the photo alone.